# Calling overloaded function from geth client

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-invocation, ganache, function-override

Attaching a `geth` client to a `ganache-cli` instance:

```
$ geth attach http://localhost:8550
Welcome to the Geth JavaScript console!

instance: EthereumJS TestRPC/v2.0.2/ethereum-js
coinbase: 0x322ecad098ba9125e5f5b35a390051af1592ab91
at block: 27 (Thu, 05 Apr 2018 15:51:09 BST)
 modules: eth:1.0 evm:1.0 net:1.0 personal:1.0 rpc:1.0 web3:1.0
```

I am attempting to call a contract function that has overloaded functions:

```
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value, bytes _data)
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) //This one is called
```

After creating an interface on `geth` to access the contract functions, calling `transfer` results in a call to the second function definition.

How can I call a specific overloaded version of a contract function?

There doesn't seem to be a way to use `encodeFunctionCall` as shown with truffle [here](https://beresnev.pro/test-overloaded-solidity-functions-via-truffle/) via `geth`.

Answer (score 1):

The `ganache-cli` version being used that was failing was `v6.0.3`. For some reason this `ganache` version could not handle overloaded contract functions well.

Updating to `v6.1.0` solves this problem.